# Stable diffeomorphisms of disks

Tags: differential-topology, homotopy-theory, geometric-topology

My impression is that computing (the homotopy groups of) $\operatorname{Diff}(n)$, the diffeomorphisms of the n-disk, is a hard problem.

For example, the connected components are related to exotic spheres. However, I think $\operatorname{Diff}(n)$ can be stabilized: there is a map of spaces
$\operatorname{Diff}(n) \rightarrow \operatorname{Diff}(n+1)$ that sends $\phi$ to $\phi \times Id_{[0,1]}$ where we make a fixed identification $D^{n+1} \cong D^n \times [0,1]$.
Let $\operatorname{Diff}^{\textrm{stable}}$ denote the colimit $\lim_{\rightarrow} \operatorname{Diff}(n)$.

**Question** What is known about $\operatorname{Diff}^{\textrm{stable}}$? Can its homotopy type (or homotopy groups) be computed in terms of something simpler?

Answers in the form of references would also be appreciated!

Comment: The Farrell-Hsiang theorem might be useful if you're interested in rational information.

Comment: @JHF can you provide a reference with this theorem? I couldn't find something with this name that seemed relevant to my question.

Comment: See for example the top of page 7 in [this note](https://www.utsc.utoronto.ca/people/kupers/wp-content/uploads/sites/50/2021/01/upenntalk.pdf).  Note that Kupers works with diffeomorphisms that fix the boundary and I don't know if it's possible to stabilize these groups in the way you're describing.